# Cannot run a simple polyglot script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to install & run Polyglot on Ubuntu 20.04. I'm using a `venv`.

I installed all requirements locally using `requirements.txt` and I installed `numpy` using `pip`.

When I try to run a simple test script with Polyglot, this error occurs:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scratches/scratch_16.py", line 1, in <module>
    from polyglot.detect import Detector
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/polyglot/detect/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import Detector, Language
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/polyglot/detect/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from icu import Locale
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/icu/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from _icu import *
ImportError: libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you just googled `python libicui18n.so.58` ? You'd have seen the answer. A quality to be a good programmer is to look for, to go deep in search, to be persistent and involved, and not waiting for other to solve the problem ;)

Comment: You need to `pip install` `PyICU` and `pycld2`

Comment: @azro yes I did and I'm not using conda, that's why that answer doesn't help me. As I said, I already installed the requirements - it still doesn't work.

Comment: You installed the 2 requirement I tell you in comment ?

Comment: @azro Yes I did, please avoid chats. We can chat here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python